# Rails 5 Mailer no Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a mailer set up in rails everything is working fine except the actual message that is supposed to be delivered. I am trying to render data from the database inside of the email that is being sent out. I keep getting a no method error. Here is what I have:

contact_recieved.html.erb

```
 <td valign="top">
    <h2 style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 22px; text-align: center;"><%=@contact.subject%></h2>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Name: <%=@contact.name%></p>

    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Email: <%=@contact.email%></p>
    <p style="color: #0f060f; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Message: <%=@contact.message%></p>
  </td>
```

Here is my contact_controller.rb:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @contact = Contact.new

  end
  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def create
    # fail
    @contact = Contact.create(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.contact_received(@contact).deliver
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
      flash[:error] = @contact.errors.full_messages
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end


  end
  private
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :subject, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

And lastly here is my contact.rb model:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    email_regex = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :name, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :subject, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true,
              :format          => {:with => email_regex }
    validates :message, :presence => true,
              :length          => { :maximum => 5000 }

end
```

When I submit the form I keep getting a no method error see image below:

[image: error message]

The data is getting stored in the database when I submit it as evidenced below:

[image: second image]

Here is the contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: "info@***********"



  def contact_received(contact)

    mail(to: "*******.com", subject: "This is just a test from Jay")
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

I changed @contacts to @contact and I am still getting the same error message:

[image: third error]

Comment: please some some code of `ContactMailer` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your mailer class to assign the variable (`@contact = contact`).

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "info@***********"



  def contact_received(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail(to: "*******.com", subject: "This is just a test from Jay")
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much I knew I was forgetting something I just couldn't pinpoint it.